# Using nichrome as a conductor?

Tags: resistors, resistance, parallel, conductors

Can we use nichrome as a conductor by connecting it in parallel with a small resistor such as 1 ohm resistor to lower its resistance?

Comment: What's the goal here? If you want a low resistance conductor, use a copper wire.

Comment: placing a resistor in parallel will not lower the resistance of the nichrome wire

Comment: @jsotola  Are you sure?  How about a 0R resistor?

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 It will short the nichrome wire, and "bypass" it, but won't lower it's resistance.

Comment: Nichrome _is_ a conductor. That is to say, it is a substance that exhibits [_electrical conductivity_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrical_resistivity_and_conductivity). But, "conductor" has other meanings. Which meaning did you have in mind?

Comment: I am having trouble thinking of any reason why you would WANT to do this. But yes, you can definitely use other metals for conductors. The best metals for conductors are copper, silver, aluminum and gold. But other metals also conduct.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  In addition, Nichrome has a lower PTC than copper.

Nichrome wire is often used as resistance wire, because it's got a high melting point (around 1400∘C) and resists oxidation well.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2flvXO7.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Yes of course you can use NiCr , Tungsten, Copper, Carbon all in parallel. The changes in current sharing depend on the temperature rise and PTC values.